# Databricks -Can we variablize the file name for while loading(mounting a file name)

Tags: python, azure-databricks, azure-notebooks

can we variablize as below if not how do we do it
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m10mS.png)

Comment: It's not recommended to use images when asking the questions - it's much easier to put text, and remove sensitive parts from it.

Comment: @malcolmrichard, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

as I see that should be the python, then just use: `.load("..../{}".format(filename))`.  If it's Scala, then you can use `.load(s".../$filename")` to substitute file name...

Answer (score 0):

You may checkout the steps to configure the variables filename while loading the mount file name:

**Step1:** Declaring the variables:

```
mountname = 'test'
csvname = 'original.csv'
path = "dbfs:/mnt/{0}/{1}".format(mountname,csvname)
```

**Step2:** Mounting the storage account

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "wasbs://test@chepra.blob.core.windows.net/",
  mount_point = "/mnt/{0}".format(mountname),
  extra_configs = {"fs.azure.sas.test.chepra.blob.core.windows.net":"gv7nXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXlOiA=="})
print("=> Succeeded")
```

**Step3:** Creating the Spark Dataframe

```
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("sep", ",").options(header= "true", inferschema='true').option('escape','"').load("{0}".format(path))
```

[image]